# How to reverse engineer a logarithmic equation

Tags: parameter-estimation

I am trying to reverse engineer the parameters of a human-designed logarithmic equation. Here are the facts:

- The equation is of the type **a = x * ( y ^ b )**
- **a** and **b** are known, **x** and **y** are unknown and need to be determined
- I have a table of values giving **b** as an exact value and **a** as the rounded integer result. For example, **b** might be 7 and **a** might be 68 where the 68 is a value rounded to the nearest integer. The number of values in the table is around 12-15 or so.
- **x** will be some number which is human selected, so it will be a relatively round number to +/- 0.05. So, for example, **x** might be 53 or 52.75, but it would not be 51.1938434.
- **y** is some positive rational value like "1.093534".

So, given the table of values of **a** and **b** and the facts above, how can I do an estimation to determine the most likely values of **x** and **y**?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the most likely values for $\log x$ and $\log y$ by linear regression since your relationship implies:

$\log a = b.\log y + \log x$

So run regression on $b$ as input and $\log a$ as output. The gradient will be $\log y$ and the intercept $\log x$